# Marvel Device buttons and input in screen not clickable

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a "dialboard" into this device's screen:

See here for a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7t3wjcf/)

```
<div class="marvel-device iphone6plus silver">
    <div class="top-bar"></div>
    <div class="sleep"></div>
    <div class="volume"></div>
    <div class="camera"></div>
    <div class="sensor"></div>
    <div class="speaker"></div>

    <div class="screen">
          <div class="inscreen">
                  <input type="text">
                  <button class="btn btn-success screen">sjdaklfjaslkjf</button>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home"></div>
    <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
</div>
```

The css for the screen is as follows:

```
.marvel-device .screen {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #111;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #111;
}

.inscreen {
  color: black;
  background: blue;
}
```

The problem is that the button inside the screen isn't clickable and the input field isn't focusable. Anyone an idea on how to make this work?

I've tried several things with z-Index and so on, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index: 3` to `.marvel-device .screen`.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h7t3wjcf/2/)**

```
.marvel-device .screen {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 3;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #111;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #111;
}
```

The reason why you need to put z-index: 3 is because on `.marvel-device.iphone6:after` you put `z-index: 2`, So `.marvel-device.iphone6:after` is positioning on top of `.marvel-device .screen`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the :after psuedo element on the iphone6plus class of the wrapper. It's z-index is 2 and is interfering with clicks. I'm not quite clear what purpose this after element serves, but removing it or reducing the z-index fixes the issue. Alternatively, you could increase the z-index of the .screen element to a number greater than 2.